# what is the difference between using deconvolution to visualize neural nets and what autoencoders do?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, tensorflow, caffe

I had a look at the paper by Zeiler [(arxiv/pdf)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901v3.pdf), and some videos of his talk on youtube, and i was attempting to reproduce it with tensorflow, and i came across something called autoencoders, that have a procedure that (to and outsider) looks similar, as in:

#### In the Paper by Zeiler:

1. Convolve input.
2. Pass it through a RELU .
3. Perform pooling.
4. ... rinse and repeat for all your layers, and when done, reverse the process back to pixel space,

#### In the autoencoder:

Compare that to an autoencoder i saw on github [(github python file)](https://github.com/loliverhennigh/All-Convnet-Autoencoder-Example/blob/master/all_conv_autoencoder.py) , that does this:

1. Convolve the input,
2. Pass it through a  RELU
3. Perform Pooling
4. ...rinse and repeat for other layers, and do the reverse back to pixel space.

So to perform a visualization of what a conv net is doing with tensorflow,
how different would the code be from this autoencoder? im stuck trying to
figure out how given a set of training data, and the trained convnet, i would visualize what an image has or does not have for it to cause an activation, as mentioned in that paper.
(one of the authors has writen a blog on this [(clarifai.com NSFW)](http://blog.clarifai.com/what-convolutional-neural-networks-see-at-when-they-see-nudity/), showing their technique, and the paper's technique was reproduced in an opensource code [(deepvis)](http://yosinski.com/deepvis) using caffe, but im unfamiliar with caffe, and new to tensorflow).
How would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a full comparison, but

- Zeiler's devonv net do the up-sampling by remembering which pixel is the max during the down-sampling(max pooling) step. There are different ways of doing this up-sampling. Potentially a convolution autoencoder can define a `conv2d_transpose` layer, which is just the reverse of `conv2d` but can learn parameters during training. Such layer seems more flexible (i.e., more parameters) than simply recording the max pixel location in Zeiler's method.
- to be added.